# Aggregate to result in current year monthly profit array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Pretty self-explanatory. 
I searched multiple mongo aggregation documentation documents, and built the query the best I could. 
Worth to point out I have almost none aggregation experience, and this is onde of the most complex aggregates I have done so far.

```
let currentYear = new Date();
        currentYear.setFullYear(currentYear.getFullYear());
        currentYear.setMonth(0);
        currentYear.setDate(1);
        await Order.aggregate([
            { $match: {
                order_ordered_on:{
                    $gte: currentYear
                },
                order_status: 'Delivered'
            }},
            { $group : { 
                _id: {month: {$month : '$order_ordered_on'}},
                total: {$sum: '$order_total'},
            }},
            { $sort : {
                _id : 1
            }},
            {$project: {
                _id:1,
                total: 1
            }}
        ]).exec((err, result) =>{
            if (err) throw err;
            let amount = result.map(a => a.total);
            res.json({
                amount
            });
        })
```

To explain my thought process, First I set a date for current year, january first until current time.
Then I match it with the *order_ordered_on* which has the date which Im working of, and the also match to select only the orders which have the *Delivered* status.
I group by *_id* to divide it in months and sum the total amount by months aswell.
Sort it in ascending order do order the array and project the resulting data.
After that I map the result to an array, which is my goal(each position in the array corresponds to a months profit).

The problem is that the total value being returned is absurd and it doesnt match what is expected. Since I dont have much experience, I could not find where Im making the aggregation mistake. 
Any help is appreciated.

To make myself clearer, Im currently using a single *Order* model, and the *order_ordered_on*, *order_status* and *order_total* fields.

The main goal of this aggregate is to split the current year profit in monthly profits, from january 1st until now, and then plot it in a graph through front-end development. The data contains Orders from 2017 until current day. The format the front-end needs to receive is that of an ordered array with the profit values.

Comment: The query works fine; I tried with some test data and get correct output too. Probably, your input data may not be as you are expecting. My test data (3 documents): `{ _id: 1, order_status: "Delivered", order_total: 200, order_ordered_on: ISODate() },
{ _id: 2, order_status: "Delivered", order_total: 18, order_ordered_on: ISODate("2019-12-02T14:00:11.001Z") },
{ _id: 3, order_status: "Delivered", order_total: 95, order_ordered_on: ISODate("2019-11-26T12:00:00.001Z") }`

Comment: @prasad_ I changed a bit of the code and added a count to check if the query results are making sense, and after some rearranging and result compare by hand, in fact the query is working as intended. 
Thank you for confirming to me that is was right, it made me check by hand the results to be sure.